# How turn on auto update content on mouse button scrolling? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I use ScrollViewer. When I scroll the page with the mouse wheel, everything works fine and the `ScrollChanged` event cause after each scroll. But when I scroll through the contents of the panel by pressing and holding the scroll bar, then `ScrollChanged` cause only when I release the mouse button. How can I fix this and make it always update the content.

Answer (score 0):

From [Pro WPF 4.5 in C#](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430243656):

> Finally, the `ButtonBase` class adds a `ClickMode` property, which determines when a button fires its `Click` event in response to mouse actions. The default value is `ClickMode.Release`, which means the `Click` event fires when the mouse is clicked and released. However, you can also choose to fire the `Click` event when the mouse button is first pressed (`ClickMode.Press`) or, oddly enough, whenever the mouse moves over the button and pauses there (`ClickMode.Hover`).

Comment: Maybe I asked wrong question. It's not what I need. I try to understand why when in panel childs only ```TextBlock```, then everything works fine, but if panel have whatever ```Image```, then update scrolling causes only when I release button mouse from ```Thumb```.